# Getting user role in Java Portlets

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I'm working with liferay server to build a portal application using portlets.

I want to display some user specific data on the website.

How can I get the role of the logged in user in liferay portlet?

my sample java code -

```
@Override
public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
    throws PortletException, IOException {
  String data = ""; 
  if(userRole = "Admin") {    //How to get this user role? 
     data = "Admin user logged in";
  } else if(userRole = "Guest"){
     data = "Guest user logged in"; 
  }
  request.setAttribute("data", data);
}
```

And JSP code -

```
<script>
    function WhoLoggedIn() {
        document.getElementById("gameForm").submit();
    }
</script>
<div onClick="WhoLoggedIn()">Click HERE</div>
<div>${data}</data>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your portlet's code you can use below method as defined in portlet specification:

```
portletRequest.isUserInRole("roleName");
```

**Note:** Liferay doesn't use the isUserInRole() method in any of the portlets provided by default. Instead it uses Liferay's permission System directly, to achieve more finegrained security.

For more information please refer to below Link

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/security-and-permissio-4

you can use some method which are there in PermissionChecker.

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
PermissionChecker permissionChecker = themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker();

permissionChecker.isCompanyAdmin() //   Returns true if the user is an administrator of their company.
permissionChecker.isOmniadmin()  //      Returns true if the user is a universal administrator.
permissionChecker.isGroupAdmin(long groupId)  //  Returns true if the user is an administrator of the group.
```

for more information about PermissionChecker  please refer to below link
http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/security/permission/PermissionChecker.html

you can also explore `RoleLocalServiceUtil`  class of Liferay

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/RoleLocalServiceUtil.html

Comment: Can i use the method isUserInRole in processAction method with ActionRequest object?

Comment: yes you can actionRequest.isUserInRole("roleName");where actionRequest is reference of ActionRequest